# Iterable function using lambda expression

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to express iterable function in lambda style?

```
const externalVal = 3;

function* myGenerator1() {
   yield 1;
   yield 2;
   yield externalVal;
   yield this.something; // might not working, use lambda expression is better
}

const myGenerator2 = () => { // error
   yield 1;
   yield 2;
   yield externalVal;
   yield this.something;
}
```

Comment: @Heyyy Marco, What are you trying to do ?

Comment: `const myGenerator2 = function* () { … }` is the expression syntax for generator functions.